# MGTwitterEngine already set what next?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mgtwitterengine

I have set MGTwitterEngine to my project. After login in I received message `Authenticated with user MyName`. But what next? I tried something like `NSLog("%@",[self.engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:1 startingAtPage:1 count:100])` and get `CFD0815B-8124-4F26-8E63-A2AB4CB830EB`. How can I get for example my last tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [good tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) that explains how to use **MGTwitterEngine** as well as  **Twitter OAuth,SAOAuthTwitterEngine** .I don't know exactly what third library you're using but i think that might be useful.